# Deleted Ubuntu partition and now I get grub rescue

Tags: grub2

I am dual booting with win8 and deleted the partition from it. After restarting I get the grub rescue prompt
 I tried to run Ubuntu off of a flashdrive and supergrub2 but neither worked and it went right back to rescue grub

Comment: Looks very similar to http://askubuntu.com/questions/271418/deleted-my-ubuntu-partition-and-now-i-get-grub-rescue#comment340459_271418.

Comment: This question is unclear: what is meant by " deleted the partition from it"? What is "the partition"? What is "it"?

Comment: "Deleted the partition from it" means deleted the Ubuntu partition from Win 8.

Comment: I can't post an answer so I write my answer here: create a ubuntu bootable USB,  then launch ubuntu from the USB, launch ubuntu terminal and write 
`sudo apt-get install syslinux` ENTER and then `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda`. To create a bootable USB : http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows, to launch ubuntu from the usb, press F11 or F12 when your computer boot (before windows start). To launch ubuntu terminal  Ctrl - Alt + T

Answer (score 1):

That once happened to me. You need to put Windows 8 installation disc in your computer and start it. Then you go to repair system and to more options and select command prompt. Then, type the following commands: bootrec /WriteMbr, bootrec /Fixboot, bootrec /Fixmbr.

It will probably say that it couldn't find any windows systems but that's normal - it will be fixed. THIS WILL DELETE GRUB AND INSTALL WINDOWS BOOTLOADER!

Comment: Dont have a windows 8 disk.

Comment: Use this to put one on a usb http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Answer (score 0):

Boot into win8 installation and you will find a repair option at lower left side of installation screen. Follow the ongoing instructions.

Comment: Dont have a windows 8 disk.

Comment: well, there are other options. You can give it a try.
use a running windows 8 PC to create a Repair Disc.
Boot with it and rebuild the MBR

Or, download Partition Wizard Bootable CD, it allows user to boot computer directly to manage partition. If it detects the windows partition then click 'Rebuild MBR' and click apply at the bottom left.